# Area of Lemniscate of Bermoulli

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I need to find out area of one loop of Lemniscate $r^2 = \sin(2\theta)$. I have tried taking square root and substitution but those haven't led to anything.

Comment: Have you learned polar integration (presumably that is what you are attempting to find the area)?

Comment: Yes, this is the easy way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total area can be calculated by [polar integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Integral_calculus_.28area.29), so you just have to evaluate the integral

$$A = \frac 1 2 \int_0^{2\pi} (r(\theta))^2 d\theta$$

In your case this is $$A=\frac 1 2  \int_0^{2\pi} |\sin(2\theta)| d\theta  = -\frac 1 4 \cos(2 x) \operatorname{sgn}(\sin(2 x))\left. \right|_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} = 4$$

One of thes loops is just $\frac 1 2 A = 2$, since we have two symmetrical loops.

Comment: There should be a factor of 1/2 in front of the integral (generally speaking). Otherwise for $r=1$ you get $2\pi$ for the area of the unit disk.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about that one.